# Loop dates and add object if not excist in JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I need to create calendar view with fullcalendar.io. To use calendar I need to create a JSON like this:

```
var db_data = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-25 15:18:46"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 1,
    "article_id": 5,
    "price": 55,
    "title": "",
    "start": "2016-03-15 15:18:46"
  } etc.
```

I need to put price at calendar from every date from period_start to period_end, but for some prices I have values in database and for other I dont have so I need to use standar price (etc.$50)...

SO I have period_start and period_end and I get some data from database but now I need to create an JSON with objects for dates which are not in database so I create code:

```
function fulljson (){
    var db_data;
    $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8888/diving/{{$article->id}}", 
                type: "GET",
                async: true, 
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                db_data = data;
                console.log(db_data);

    // declare variables
    var period_start = new Date('{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($article->from)) }}'),
        period_end = new Date('{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($article->to)) }}'),
        current_date = period_start,
        array_of_all_dates = [];

    // Create a populated array of dates
    while (current_date.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()) {
      array_of_all_dates.push(current_date);
      current_date = new Date(+current_date);
      current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
    }

    // Now loop over the array of populated dates and mutate, so something like
    array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
      var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
        return new Date(db_data.start.replace(" ", "T")).getTime() === date.getTime(); // I need to do this comparison better!
      });
      if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
        return found_in_db[0];
      }
      var new_object = {
        title: '',
        start: date,
        price: '{{$article->price}}'
      };
      console.log(new_object);
      return new_object;

    });
    console.log('result'+array_of_all_dates);
    drawCalendar(array_of_all_dates);
                }, 
                error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('ERROR');
                }      
    });

};

    $(document).ready(function() {
    fulljson();

    });

    function drawCalendar(data) {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'next'
            },
            defaultDate: Date.now(),

            eventRender: function(event, element) {
            element.find("fc-event-container").remove();    
    element.find(".fc-content").remove();
    element.find(".fc-event").remove();
    var new_description =   
         '<div style="display:inline-flex; float:right;"><div class="col-md-6"style="margin-top:5px";><p class="price">' + event.price + 'e</p></div>';

    element.append(new_description);
} ,// allow "more" link when too many events
            events: data,
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
    }

        });
};
```

And now this code work in Chrome: [image]

But in FireFox I get this: [image]

Please look at 1.2.3. February where I have data from database. You will see the changes.

SO why this code work in Chrome and dont work in Firefox? What is a problem? Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

Comment: How I can solve this comparation better: while (current_date.getTime() <= period_end.getTime()) {
      array_of_all_dates.push(current_date);
      current_date = new Date(+current_date);
      current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    array_of_all_dates = array_of_all_dates.map(function (date) {
      var found_in_db = db_data.filter(function (db_data) {
        return new Date(db_data.start).getTime() === date.getTime();
      });
      if (found_in_db.length > 0) {
        return found_in_db[0];
      }
     ...

Comment: I'm having difficulty seeing the difference between the two screen shots. What is 1.2.3?

Comment: Please see the dates 1. Feb,2. Feb, 3 Feb ... prices ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SO why this code work in Chrome and dont work in Firefox?

Because the date strings provided are not valid and Firefox will transpose those to `invalid date` when passed to `new Date()`. Chrome however does parse them but this is not expected behavior cross browser

Send valid ISO strings from server or any format recommended in plugin docs

**From fullcalender docs:**

> When specifying Event Objects for events or eventSources, you may
>   specify a string in IETF format (ex: "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"),
>   a string in ISO8601 format (ex: "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX
>   timestamp.

Comment: that needs to be fixed at server, I don't know what server language you are using. Did you look in docs as suggested?

Comment: This is screenshoot of mysql database: http://i.imgur.com/OPyc8Rp.png and column start is a TIMESTAMP ...

Comment: so you need to format the dates properly to be read by javascript when pulled from database. Database server knows what timezone it lives in and can work with that format, but browser doesn't know that timezone or what date reference you are sending without formatting it

Comment: but I format here with Laravel blade: var period_start = new Date('{{ date('Y-m-d', strtotime($article->from)) }}'), so format is Y-m-d

Comment: did you read the fullcalendar reference documents? Everything you need is explained there.

Comment: I read it but I dont know how to solve problem. Please help. Can you please write a jssfiddle with solution... How to make it readable to fullcalendar...

Comment: format the dates at server. Not hard to look up how to do that in php manual or MySQL manual. I even added the expected formats in the question. What you need to do is easy to research

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH. I solve my problem with: public function getStartAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->toRfc2822String();
    }... Is there any better solution for my problems with dates loop ? What you suggest to make better ?